# Insert/Update unique numerical value in SQL Server Compact Edition

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I tried this piece of SQL against a SQL Server CE database, but it didn't work:

```
INSERT INTO [ClientProperties] ([ClientId], [ProviderName], [ObjectName], [PropertyKey],
[PropertyValue], [TickCount])
VALUES ('164C3267-9D09-48F0-B6BB-2A031F7661D4', 'Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz', 'Qux', (SELECT COALESCE(MAX(TickCount), 0) + 1 FROM ClientProperties))
```

It returns the following message:

> There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 3,Token line offset = 75,Token in error = SELECT ]

So if I can't do it that way, how do I make sure that `TickCount` stays unique and increments even if multiple processes are trying to insert or update rows at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax when using a select in an insert statement is

```
INSERT INTO [ClientProperties] ([ClientId], [ProviderName], [ObjectName], [PropertyKey], [PropertyValue], [TickCount])
SELECT '164C3267-9D09-48F0-B6BB-2A031F7661D4', 
       'Foo', 
       'Bar',
       'Baz',
       'Qux',
        COALESCE(MAX(TickCount), 0) + 1 
FROM ClientProperties
```

Comment: Thanks. I haven't worked with raw SQL in too long. It's kind of embarrassing that I had to ask this question.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `INSERT` query to look something like below using `INSERT INTO .. SELECT FROM` construct

```
INSERT INTO [ClientProperties] (
[ClientId], 
[ProviderName], 
[ObjectName], 
[PropertyKey],
[PropertyValue], 
[TickCount])
SELECT '164C3267-9D09-48F0-B6BB-2A031F7661D4', 
'Foo', 
'Bar', 
'Baz', 
'Qux',
COALESCE(MAX(TickCount), 0) + 1 
FROM ClientProperties
```

Comment: Yours and juergen's answers came in almost at the same time, but he beat you about half a minute, so since both your answers were correct, it felt the most fair to hand him the answer checkmark. Thanks for answering, though. I gave you a +1 at least. :)